# tmux / screen ctrl+arrow (left right) doesn't work on SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, tmux, gnu-screen

I've configured `tmux` to skip words on Ctrl+right / left :

`set-window-option -g xterm-keys on`

It works just fine, but as I do SSH, it doesn't work and prints `;5D` or `;5C`..

The same issue occurred when I used `screen`, is there some specific configuration for `tmux`/`screen` on SSH ?

Comment: Also posted on UNIX & Linux: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/186964/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not tmux nor screen that "skips words"; the text input is provided by your *shell*. You must therefore find out what key sequence Ctrl+arrows generate, and teach your shell that it means "skip a word". Otherwise, it will stop interpreting mid-sequence because it's not recognized.

If you're using bash, it takes some of the key definitions from ncurses/terminfo, and others from the "inputrc" file. So first make sure you have the ncurses terminal definitions installed ("ncurses-term" or similar). And if you have a custom `~/.inputrc`, tell it to import the system-wide one, using:

```
$include /etc/inputrc
```

If that doesn't help, add a custom mapping to your ~/.inputrc file (on the server, of course):

1. In bash, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> (the "verbatim input" key), followed by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>. You'll see the "Ctrl+right" escape sequence inserted as plain text:

   ```
   ^[[1;5C
   ```

   The `^[` means an "ESC" character; the rest are plain text. So this is `ESC [ 1 ; 5 C`.
2. In `man bash`, find the inputrc ("readline") command for skipping a word. (It's `forward-word`.)
3. In `~/.inputrc`, add both the key sequence and the command. (The "ESC" is written as `\e`.)

   ```
   "\e[1;5C": forward-word
   ```
4. Repeat the same for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>←</kbd>.
5. Close ssh, then connect again and see if it works.

Note that most distributions already have these particular mappings in `/etc/inputrc`.

Comment: I can't edit anything on the server itself. Adding `"\e[1;5C": forward-word` to ` ~/.inputrc` (on my system) doesn't help.

Comment: @SagiLow: Of course it doesn't help – the server can't see what files the client has... There's really nothing the client could do to fix this, anyway.

Comment: my colleagues who uses Ubuntu 12 manage to this this just fine, even when connecting to the same remote system. I don't think it cannot be done

Comment: bash uses none of the extended key-definitions from the terminal database (such as the "ctrl+arrow" in the question).  For that, it relies exclusively on the user's `.inputrc` file.

Comment: And, strictly speaking, .inputrc and command names, line editing and history belong to GNU readline, not bash. (Only do not make a CLISP mistake: it's GPL, not LGPL. For non-GPL programs, there is libedit).